# List operation depending on condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list` of numbers. Each time the absolute difference between two consecutive numbers exceeds a `threshold` from this position up to the end, the list should be increased by `increase`.

My solution:

```
list = {3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 7, 8, 7, 9, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 5, 5};

threshold = 5;
increase = 10;

diffList = Abs[Differences[list]]

{4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 8, 2, 5, 3, 0}

pos = Flatten@Position[diffList, n_ /; n >= threshold]

{5, 9, 13, 15, 17}

modifiedList = list;

Do[
  modifiedList[[pos[[i]] + 1 ;; All]] = modifiedList[[pos[[i]] + 1 ;; All]] + increase;
  , {i, 1, Length@pos}
  ];

(* desired resulting list *)

modifiedList

{3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 17, 18, 17, 19, 23, 26, 22, 23, 38, 39, 41, 43, 58, 55, 55}

Show[
 ListLinePlot[{list, modifiedList}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  PlotLabels -> {"list", "modifiedList"}],
 Graphics[{Dashed, 
     Line[{{pos[[#]] + 1, 0}, {pos[[#]] + 1, Max@modifiedList}}]}] & /@
   Range[Length@pos]
 ]
```

[image]

**Question**: How can I replace the `Do` loop or can you propose another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 7, 8, 7, 9, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 5, 5};

threshold = 5;
increase = 10;
```

Breaking into steps:

```
inc = (increase Boole[# >= threshold]) & /@ Abs@Differences@list
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0}

```
acc = {0}~Join~Accumulate@inc
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50,
>   50, 50}

```
list + acc
```

> {3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 17, 18, 17, 19, 23, 26, 22, 23, 38, 39, 41, 43, 58,
>   55, 55}

```
% == modifiedList
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

```
i = 0;
Prepend[MapThread[(If[#2 >= threshold, i += increase];
    #1 + i) &, {Rest@list, diffList}], First[list]]
```

> {3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 17, 18, 17, 19, 23, 26, 22, 23, 38, 39, 41, 43, 58, 55, 55}

Answer (score 3):

```
l2 = list + Accumulate[increase UnitStep[Join[{0}, diffList] - threshold]];

l3 = Join @@ MapIndexed[# + increase (#2[[1]] - 1) &, Split[list, Abs@Subtract@## < 5 &]];

l2  == l3 == modifiedList
```

> True

Comment: Could you please have a look on that question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189592/removing-non-associated-2d-points-for-preparing-remaining-data-as-input-for-a-ge